# Ruby on Rails Example

Tags: lead-conversion, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app from which I would like to convert a lead and merge it with an existing account. Does anyone have some sample code using Ruby? I have found C# and Java examples and understand the convert() method, but would love to see it done in Ruby.

Comment: Have you looked at the databasedotcom gem?

Answer (score 1):

The `convertLead` method is AFAIK only available in the (older) SOAP API. databasedotcom builds on the REST API.

As with any other language, you could start from the WSDL - here is a blog post on that [Ruby and Salesforce Integration with SOAP](http://techsahre.blogspot.ie/2011/01/ruby-and-salesforce-integration-with.html).

Google produced these two hits:

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/d/DerGuteMoritz-rforce-0.4.2/ConvertLead.html) (https://rubygems.org/gems/DerGuteMoritz-rforce)
- https://github.com/BinaryMuse/rforce-wrapper/search?q=convertLead

which might (or might not) be better places to start from.

There is some sample code here https://github.com/BinaryMuse/rforce-wrapper but not for convert lead.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [Dailyforce](https://github.com/briandiaz/dailyforce) a Example of Ruby on Rails with Salesforce

Comment: can u add some more details to your answer and be specific on how this example / library is going to address the question.

Comment: Basically  i wanted to show a way of using Ruby with Salesforce, using gems that have the ability to do any query a user needs with [restforce](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce) and with the authentication [omniauth-salesforce](https://github.com/realdoug/omniauth-salesforce).